# What does the following piece of code actually do?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, request

There is test method which accepts `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`. It returns `ModelAndView`. Before returing the model and view object the response is being redirected to /xyz . If I omit `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/xyz");` line of code then the URL in my browser is `localhost:8080/project/abc` however adding that line of code makes the URL in the browser `localhost:8080/project/xyz`.

```
 public ModelAndView test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        LOGGER.info("Request for dashboard ");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/xyz");
        modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Now if I donot set the view name in the above code then it results in an error.

```
public ModelAndView test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            LOGGER.info("Request for dashboard ");
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/xyz");
            return modelAndView;
        }
```

What exactly is happining under covers?

Comment: what exactly is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you refered to the JavaDoc? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html